# construct a sql , assign it to a variable and execute inside shell script

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to execute a mysql query inside my shell script, which is not executing .
Here is what i am trying to do

```
query="\"select count(*) from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('mysql','performance_schema','information_schema') and engine!='INNODB';\""
```

echo $query

```
"select count(*) from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('mysql','performance_schema','information_schema') and engine!='INNODB';"
```

Inside my shell script , i am executing below which is not working. It is not giving any error but simply not considering -e option and listing down all the valid options for mysql client.

```
mysql -u$username -p$password -e$query
```

I even validated below in my shell prompt

```
echo "mysql -uroot -p -e$query"
mysql -uroot -p -e"select count(*) from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('mysql','performance_schema','information_schema') and engine!='INNODB';"
```

which is perfectly fine and executes without any issues. I am not sure what to do now. please help.Thanks

Comment: Why do you put quotes inside your query string?

Comment: @mustaccio : because i wanted to construct and execute my sql query as like i would manually do in shell prompt. But even without qoutes also its not working

Comment: It is quite possible.  But it is easy to be tripped up by quoting and escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
query="select count(*) from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA not in ('mysql','performance_schema','information_schema') and engine!='INNODB'"
mysql -uroot -p -e"${query}"
```

or

```
query="select count(*) from information_schema.tables"
query="${query} where TABLE_SCHEMA not in"
query="${query} ('mysql','performance_schema','information_schema')"
query="${query} and engine!='INNODB'"
mysql -uroot -p -e"${query}"
```

Double quotes do not need to be part of the `query` variable

Comment: Thank you so much . This will help me in lot of automation.

Comment: @udhayandharmalingam if my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark.